# Dataset's query from VB to C# doesn't give the same Column MaxLength

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm rewriting a winform VB software to C# winform then I have this problem:
There's a data set ntlsDataSet and a data table inside named SOT which have the query GetDataByNew.
In VB the code is:

```
 Dim SOAdpt As New SOTTableAdapter
 Dim dtNewSO As DataTable = SOAdpt.GetDataByNew(spt)
```

and I rewrite it on C# like so:

```
 var SOAdpt = new SOTTableAdapter();
 DataTable dtNewSO = SOAdpt.GetDataByNew(DateTime.Parse(spt));
```

It's all good and all, but then I realize in C# the query only have the MaxLength from dtNewSO Column is only 1 while on VB it's 4, everything else is similar except that so it throw me exception.
Is there anyway for C# to return the table with the MaxLength as 4 like VB? I tried .FillSchema() but it still doesn't work I didn't use it the right way

Comment: Look at the appropriate `DataTable` in the `DataSet` designer. It must be different in the C# project. Why exactly that is is not clear as you haven't provided enough information to determine that.

Comment: It seem the table from the VB project are not the same as C# project. And so it result in the problem. So is there anyway can I copy the data table from one dataset to another project dataset?